# Is this white powdery substance on a wood shelf caused by flying termites?

Tags: wood, pest-control, wooden-furniture, pest, termite

There were probably about 100 or 200 so flying termites inside the house two days ago. They were all flying to the ceiling lights, and I placed buckets of water below it and many got in. I also vacuumed the termites in the air and nearly all are gone now. They seem to be coming from inside of the house and the professionals are coming in later in the week.

I noticed this whitish powder on my wood shelf. Are they the eggs of these termites? Or their droppings?  Should I just wipe them away?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a popcorn ceiling?

Comment: @Monso, No I don't.

Comment: Termite Control : What Do Termite Eggs Look Like?  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7wITnSRyaAA

Comment: Did you find out what it was? I found similar piles of powder on one step leading up to the attic and in one window frame. But they did not reoccur.

Comment: @KaushikGhose, no I never found out what it was. Sorry.

Comment: I wonder if it is a borate compound used for Termite control?

Comment: @cVplZ, no, it's not.

Answer (score -2):

If you saw swarming termites in your house two years ago, I hope you had you house treated. If not, they have your home as the food menu.